# Generate signature using RSA-SHA256 for Oauth 1.0 in PHP

Tags: php

How to generate signature using RSA-SHA256 for Oauth 1.0 Authentication API consumption?
Is there any inbuilt function available for it in PHP. I want to generate oauth_signature for consuming /oauth/request_token end-point on https://www.interactivebrokers.com/webtradingapi/

I am not getting the way to generate the signature. Can anyone also provide a link explaining the RSA-SHA256 algorithm. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I think you need to take a look at [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

Comment: @Alon Eitan, I have used it for HMAC-SHA1, but how to go for RSA-SHA256 using it. Also need to know is RSA-SHA256 is a hybrid algorithm of RSA and SHA-256? hash_hmac() seems to provide facility for sha256 but what about RSA part. RSA being asymmetric cryptographic algo and hash_hmac seems to deal only with the hashing algos

Comment: I see, so perhaps [openssl_sign()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php), it has an option for `sha256WithRSAEncryption`